# What does the RORX instruction do?

Tags: x86

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets)

> RORX instruction, Rotate right logical without affecting flags

I was just going through the bit manipulation instructions and found this one which I don't understand. Enlighten me please. Google search can't seem to help me on this one.

Most informative thing I found was this [patent](http://www.google.com/patents/US20110161635) on the instruction, but it's a really long read and I just want to know this instruction does.

Comment: An [instruction set reference](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/) is useful [RORX](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/RORX.html) is described there.

Comment: I think the text you quoted says it all. It simply rotates right (bits that "fall off" on the right are shifted in on the left again) but does not use nor affect any of the CPU flags.

Comment: Not affecting the flags can be pretty useful, it avoids out-of-order execution stalls.

Comment: new instructions in x86 with the `X` suffix (such as mulx, shrx, adcx, adox...) all don't affect the flags (or change the flag in a different way than before)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, `RORX` is just a version of `ROR` which doesn't affect flags, and also allows to specify a destination register (so the source isn't necessarily overwritten - thanks to Peter in the comments for pointing this out). And `ROR` is basically a version of `SHR` which shifts the bits around, so that bits falling off at the right come back at the left.

---

To help you understand: There are three kinds of instructions to shift right.

#### 1) `SHR`, shift logical right

- On the right side, shifts bits away into the nirvana (cut off)
- On the left side, shifts in zeroes

  - As a consequence, SHR-ing negative values will make them positive because the sign bit is shifted away and replaced by a zero)

Example:

```
00110011 SHR 3

>>>00110011
00000110         "011" thrown away, "000" shifted in

---

11001100 SHR 3

>>>11001100
00011001         "100" thrown away, "000" shifted in
```

#### 2) `SAR`, shift arithmetic right

- On the right side, shifts bits away into the nirvana (cut off)
- On the left side, shifts in either ones or zeroes depending on the value of the sign bit (the most significant bit) of the original value

  - As a consequence, SAR-ing negative values will *keep their sign negative* because the sign bit stays and is used to fill the new positions
  - For positive values (where the sign bit is zero), SAR will do the same as SHR
  - The shift is called "arithmetic" because it is equivalent to a division by 2^X where X is the number of bits you are shifting

Example:

```
00110011 SAR 3

>>>00110011
00000110         "011" thrown away, "000" shifted in

---

11001100 SAR 3

>>>11001100
11111001         "100" thrown away, "111" shifted in
```

#### 3) `ROR`, rotate right

- On the right side, shifts bits around back to the left side
- On the left side, shifts those bits in which "fell of" from the right side

Example:

```
00110011 ROR 3

>>>00110011
01100110         "011" rotated around, shifted out right and back in left

---

11001100 ROR 3

>>>11001100
10011001         "100" rotated around, shifted out right and back in left
```

*(For shifting left, there are only two, `SHL` and `ROL`, because a `SAL` instruction wouldn't make sense because it would be no different from `SHL`.)*

---

And for the question what the "doesn't affect flags" part is supposed to mean: Most of the operations set or clear processor flags (check out the `EFLAGS` register) in a certain way, indicating for example that an overflow occured, or that the result was zero. These flags can, for example, be used in conditional branch instructions (a operation such as `cmp` sets the flags, and then the following `je` uses the flags to determine what the result of the comparison was and whether or not to jump).

The `ROR` instruction usually also sets some flags, but `RORX` leaves them untouched. This and the fact that `RORX` allows specifying a destination different from the source and that it allows only immediate operands (thanks, Peter Cordes, for adding this in the comments) are the only differences. (And of course that `RORX` isn't available on all x86 processors, while `ROR` is.)

Comment: The most important difference IMO between `ror` and `rorx` is that [`rorx` copies and rotates](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/RORX.html): the destination register doesn't have to be the same as the source register.  Also, that it's only available with an immediate operand.